# How does Java put windows onto the desktop?

Tags: java, swing

The idea of my program is to "sandbox" the UI of java swing applications(not the entire program).  My program will run the target Java application, and any swing frames/dialogs/containers that the target creates, will be placed in an internal frame in my program.

So in short, I need a way to "intercept" Java windows and display them in my own Frame.

I've been searching through the Java source to find how it displays windows, without luck. Any tips?

Edit:
Disregard this question.

Comment: How is your code related to the class you're intercepting? Are they going to be in the same jvm or  different processes altogether?

Comment: Ideally, it will be the same JVM. The target application will most likely be a Jar file. So Ill have to figure out how to run the target in the same JVM.

Answer (score 1):

> How to run a jar in the same JVM after my program has set things up

Start a thread and have it execute the JAR's main method, extracted from the JAR's manifest `main-class` entry.